# Combine and create array

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array

Who can help me to combine 2 array into one like this:

```
array(2) { ["localitatea"]=> array(1) { [0]=> string(10) "București" } ["sector"]=> array(2) { [0]=> string(1) "1" [1]=> string(1) "2" } }
```

with this data from cookies

```
$cookie_ansamblu = $_COOKIE['ansamblu'];
$a_cookies = str_replace(str_split('\\/:*?"<>|[]'), ' ', $cookie_ansamblu);
```

Value of this is: Yes, No

```
$cookie_localitatea = $_COOKIE['localitatea'];
$l_cookies = str_replace(str_split('\\/:*?"<>|[]'), ' ', $cookie_localitatea);
```

Value : 1, 2, 3

```
$cookie_nivele = $_COOKIE['nivele'];
$n_cookies = str_replace(str_split('\\/:*?"<>|[]'), ' ', $cookie_nivele);
```

Value : 1, 2, 3

```
$cookie_sector = $_COOKIE['sector'];
$s_cookies = str_replace(str_split('\\/:*?"<>|[]'), ' ', $cookie_sector);
```

Value : 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6

```
$cookie_localitati_limitrofe = $_COOKIE['localitati_limitrofe'];
$ll_cookies = str_replace(str_split('\\/:*?"<>|[]'), ' ', $cookie_localitati_limitrofe);
```

Value : 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6,8,9,10
$array_all = array('ansamblu', 'nivele', 'localitatea', 'sector', 'localitati_limitrofe');

and this is what i try to do but whithout succes:

Try1:

```
$choices = array_combine($array_all, array($a_cookies, $n_cookies, $l_cookies,  $s_cookies, $ll_cookies));
```

Try 2:

```
$choicess = array (
    'ansamblu' => 
        array ($a_cookies),
    'localitatea' => 
        array ($l_cookies),
    'nivele' => 
        array ($n_cookies), 
    'sector' => 
        array ($s_cookies),
    'localitati_limitrofe' => 
        array ($ll_cookies),
);
```

Comment: `$choicess = ['localitatea' => $l_cookies, 'ansamblu' => $a_cookies, ...]`?

Answer (score 0):

i store cookies in this mode:

```
// handle checkboxes - send to cookies
    $('input[name="ansamblu[]"').on('click', function() {
        var ansamblu_array = [];

        // add to array
        $('#ansamblu:checked').each(function() {
            ansamblu_array.push($(this).attr('data-at'));
        });
        ansamblu_array = ansamblu_array.filter(function (el) {
          return el != null;
        });
        // stringify array object
        ansamblu_array = JSON.stringify(ansamblu_array);
        console.log(ansamblu_array);

        // set cookie
        $.cookie('ansamblu', ansamblu_array, {path:'/'});
    });
    $('input[name="localitatea[]"').on('click', function() {
        var localitatea_array = [];

        // add to array
        $('#localitatea:checked').each(function() {
            localitatea_array.push($(this).attr('data-at'));
        });
        localitatea_array = localitatea_array.filter(function (el) {
          return el != null;
        });
        // stringify array object
        localitatea_array = JSON.stringify(localitatea_array);
        console.log(localitatea_array);

        // set cookie
        $.cookie('localitatea', localitatea_array, {path:'/'});
    });
    $('input[name="nivele[]"').on('click', function() {
        var nivele_array = [];

        // add to array
        $('#nivele:checked').each(function() {
            nivele_array.push($(this).attr('data-at'));
        });
        nivele_array = nivele_array.filter(function (el) {
          return el != null;
        });
        // stringify array object
        nivele_array = JSON.stringify(nivele_array);
        console.log(nivele_array);

        // set cookie
        $.cookie('nivele', nivele_array, {path:'/'});
    });
          
    $('input[name="sector[]"').on('click', function() {
        var sector_array = [];

        // add to array
        $('#sector:checked').each(function() {
            sector_array.push($(this).attr('data-at'));
        });
        sector_array = sector_array.filter(function (el) {
          return el != null;
        });
        // stringify array object
        sector_array = JSON.stringify(sector_array);
        
        console.log(sector_array);
        // set cookie
        $.cookie('sector', sector_array, {path:'/'});
    });
    $('input[name="localitati_limitrofe[]"').on('click', function() {
        var localitati_limitrofe_array = [];

        // add to array
        $('#localitati_limitrofe:checked').each(function() {
            localitati_limitrofe_array.push($(this).attr('data-at'));
        });
        localitati_limitrofe_array = localitati_limitrofe_array.filter(function (el) {
          return el != null;
        });
        // stringify array object
        localitati_limitrofe_array = JSON.stringify(localitati_limitrofe_array);
        
        console.log(localitati_limitrofe_array);
        // set cookie
        $.cookie('localitati_limitrofe', localitati_limitrofe_array, {path:'/'});
    });
```

i do

```
$cookie_sector = $_COOKIE['sector'];
$s_cookies = str_replace(str_split('\\/:*?"<>|[]'), ' ', $cookie_sector);
```

and result is

```
 1 , 2
```

when i do what Justinas say

result is:

```
 ["sector"]=> array(1) { [0]=> string(13) " 1 , 2 " }
```

no split into two array